# Apply background-color to dxDataGrid control and export to Excel

Tags: javascript, devexpress, devextreme, jszip

I'm using DevExpress's `dxDataGrid` in a ASP.NET project for show some data stored on a SQL Server database.

The following code shows how I'm setting the `dxDataGrid` control for render the data:

```
// Variables.
var vlrMin = [];     
var vlrMax = [];     
var vlr_to_match = 0;
var colors = [];     
var final_rst = "";

// Add values to variables:
vlrMin.push("9");
vlrMin.push("2");
vlrMin.push("9");

// Add values to variables:
vlrMax.push("13");
vlrMax.push("7");
vlrMax.push("4");

colors.push('#ff0000');
colors.push('#92D050');
colors.push('#5B9BD5');

// Start configuration.
$("#gridContainer").dxDataGrid({
    dataSource: [{
        "Dept": "Local services",
        "Employee": "John Doe",
        "TotalHours": "11"
    }],
    paging: {
        pageSize: 10
    },
    export: {
        allowExportSelectedData: true,
        enabled: true,
        fileName: 'Reporte 1',
        texts: {
            exportAll: 'Export all',
            exportSelectedRows: 'Export selected row(s).',
            exportTo: 'Export'
        },
    },
    searchPanel: {
        visible: true
    },
    filterRow: {
        visible: true,
        showOperationChooser: true
    },
    allowColumnReordering: true,
    grouping: {
        autoExpandAll: true
    },
    groupPanel: {
        visible: true
    },
    pager: {
        showPageSizeSelector: true,
        allowedPageSizes: [5, 10, 20],
        showInfo: true
    },
    columns: ['Dept',
        'Employee', {
            dataField: 'TotalHours',
            allowFiltering: true,
            allowSorting: true,
            cellTemplate: function(container, options) {
                /* Value to check if matches with the criteria. */
                var vlr_to_match = options.value;

                /* Loop elements. */
                for (var mn = 0; mn < vlrMin.length; mn++) {
                    if (vlr_to_match >= vlrMin[mn] && vlr_to_match <= vlrMax[mn]) {
                        final_rst = colors[mn];
                        break;
                    }
                }

                /* Apply custom style to element. */
                $('<span>').text(options.data.TotalHours)
                    .attr('style', 'background-color: ' + final_rst)
                    .appendTo(container);
            }
        }
    ]
});
```

This is the results in the `dxDataGrid` control:

[image: Results from dxDataGrdi control]

But, when I open the generated file "using the DevExpress functionality" I'm not getting the same results as is shown in the screenshot *(i.e; the cell has values, but no styles are applied)*.

According to the [documentation](https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/#demo/data_grid-templates-column_3rd_party_engine_template), and after [apply a color to an specific cell](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T217765) in the `dxDataGrid` control, when the exported Excel file is opened, the cell is not getting the same result as is shown in the `dxDataGrid` control.

My question is:

- How can apply styles to a `dxDataGrid` cell and apply such results to the generated Excel file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

unfortunately, based on the quite recent (2016-09-20) reply from DX stuff in their support forum, there is no way in DevExtreme suit to export dxDataGrid to excel with formatting.

See yourself: https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T429240

If you were using the DevEpress ASPxGridView control together with ASPxGridViewExporter you would be able to customize format in the exported Excel doc per cell or per row.